# Return the sum of a group if the sum is negative

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, group-by, sum

I'm trying to determine the logic/syntax to query a table and get any rows that have a negative sum for a specific group. For Example:

```
  ID   | Month  | Amt Due
------ | ------ | ------
  1    |  Jan   |   15
------ | ------ | ------
  1    |  Jan   |  -20
------ | ------ | ------
  1    |  Mar   |   3
------ | ------ | ------ 
  2    |  Aug   |   13
------ | ------ | ------
  2    |  Dec   |   40
------ | ------ | ------  
  2    |  Dec   |  -25
------ | ------ | ------
```

Essentially, the query would see that there are two ID's with more than one of the same month:

- ID1, Jan
- ID2, Dec

It would then take the sum of the *amt due* column:

- Jan (-5)
- Dec (15)

Since I only want the negatives, the final result would be:

```
 ID    | Month  | SUM(Amt Due)
------ | ------ | ------
  1    |  Jan   |   -5
------ | ------ | ------
```

This is being used to identify ID's that have a negative sum for any one month because the system should never generate a negative amt_due sum.

Comment: if there is only one record in a group with a negative amount, should you return that row as well?

Comment: Yes, if there is any month with a negative sum it should be returned.

Comment: Do you need to generate summary rows (just like you show in your post), or would it be helpful to see the individual rows for such `ID, Month` combinations? vkp already gave you the answer if you only need the summary. Seeing the individual rows that make up these combinations is also relatively easy - using analytic functions instead of aggregates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `group by` with a `having` condition.

```
select id,month,sum(amt_due) 
from tablename 
group by id,month
having sum(amt_due) < 0
```

If this check should happen only for groups with more than 1 row, add one more condition `and count(*) > 1`. The query would be

```
select id,month,sum(amt_due) 
from tablename 
group by id,month
having sum(amt_due) < 0 and count(*) > 1
```

Edit: Per OP's comment, the query should be

```
select tb1.acct_num, tb2,inv_id, tb3.acctinv_id, to_char(tb3.frm_dt, 'MON'), sum(tb3.amt_due), tb3.type_id 
from table1 tb1 
join table2 tb2 on tb1.inv_id = tb2.inv_id
join table3 tb3 on tb2.acctinv_id = tb3.acctinv_id 
where tb3.type_id = 10 
group by tb1.acct_num, tb2,inv_id, tb3.acctinv_id, to_char(tb3.frm_dt, 'MON'), tb3.type_id
having sum(tb3.amt_due) < 0
```

I am not sure if you need all those columns for grouping. You were getting an error because, all the non-aggregate columns being selected were not included in `group by`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! Here is what I have so far with a few joins and I keep getting: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression:

    select   tb1.acct_num, tb2,inv_id, tb3.acctinv_id,
                to_char(tb3.frm_dt, 'MON'), sum(tb3.amt_due), tb3.type_id
    from     table1 tb1, table2 tb2, table3 tb3
    where   tb1.inv_id        =  tb2.inv_id      and
                 tb2.acctinv_id = tb3.acctinv_id and
                 tb3.type_id = 10
    group by tb1.acct_num, tb3.frm_dt
    having sum(tb3.amt_due) < 0;

Comment: thank you! I deleted a lot of the columns for the actual grouping to be correct (I didn't want grouping by inv_id or acctinv_id, just acct_num). I also forgot to add the to_char. All is working now!